# Filtering list using stream take long time

Tags: java, stream, java-stream

I have list of tasks about 700 task or more
i am trying to search by taskId using below code.
it works but it takes a lot of time about 1 minute.
list is not sorted

```
List<Tasks> tasks = ....;
tasks = tasks
        .stream()
        .filter(task -> task.getTaskId().equals("1000"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

looping tasks take the same time almost

How to enhance my code?

Regards

Comment: The `filter` operation itself is very fast. What is your `Task` class? In particular, is it a JPA entity that's being lazy-loaded from a database on read?

Comment: Seems very odd as 700 objects is really not much. What exactly is a Tasks obejct? What does `getTaskId()` do? Is that a long running operation (network access etc.)? You can however use a Map which stores ID and the associated task if you want to speed things up.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-
it's just wrapper class no thing more

Comment: Your `task.getTaskId()` seems to have some complex logic and `Stream` API can not do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

On my system, the following example prints:
`Filtering 700 records took 10210465ns and found 69 matches.`
So that's 10ms compared to your 1 minute. (And the JIT compiler wouldn't have a chance to fully kick in.)

Use a profiler to find out where the time is spent in your application. I suspect your `getTaskID` method is doing more than you think.

```
public class Filter {
    static Random rng = new Random();

    static record Task(String id){};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int howMany = 700;
        List<Task> tasks = makeTasks(howMany, 0.1f);
        long before = System.nanoTime();
        tasks = tasks
                .stream()
                .filter(task -> task.id().equals("1000"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        long after = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Filtering "+howMany+" records took "+(after-before)+"ns and found "+tasks.size()+" matches.");
    }
    
    static List<Task> makeTasks(int howMany, float probabilityOfMatch) {
        var list = new ArrayList<Task>(howMany);
        for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++) {
            var id = Integer.toString((rng.nextFloat() < probabilityOfMatch ? 1000 : i));
            list.add(new Task(id));
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
        return list;
    }
}
```